# Why does "sudo ./foo" return "./foo Command not found"?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I'm having trouble with my new Raspberry Pi.  Any time I try to run `./foo`, it returns
`-bash: ./foo: Permission denied`

But if I try to run `sudo ./bar`, then it returns
`sudo: ./bar: command not found`

Using `sudo` with other things (for example: `ifdown` and `ifup`) works fine, but any script that I've downloaded or written, it refuses to execute.

I'm pretty familiar with bash, but mostly in the context of Mac OS X. It just seems to me that this should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the script permissions to executable:

```
chmod +x ./foo  # or sudo chmod +x ./foo
./foo
```

Comment: Thanks, that's all it was. I'm just not used to having to do that manually for each script.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like foo is not executable.  You can fix this by executing `chmod +x foo`, then `./foo` or `sudo ./foo` The alternative to making it executable would be to pass it to `sh` as an argument.  You can run it this way by typing `sh ./foo` or `sudo sh ./foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the executable bit of the file. For instance

```
$ ls -l might return 
-rw-rw-r--   1 hacker hacker        28 Jan 17 11:32 foo

$ chmod 775 foo
```

Change as appropriate for the user you want to be able to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the permissions bits for the files `./foo` and `./bar`. In the first case `./foo` is likely either not executable at all or isn't executable for the root user. When you run `sudo` you're typically elevating your privileges so that you're the root user.

If you're permissions are set like this on file `./foo` it won't execute for userX.

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r--   1 userX groupX          14 Jan 17 11:32 foo
```

If they're like this it will execute for userX.

```
$ chmod u+x foo
$ ls -l
-rwxrw-r--   1 userX groupX          14 Jan 17 11:32 foo
```

However root will still not be able to execute it, since the 3 grouping of permissions (rwxrw-r--) doesn't allow other users to execute `./foo`. You can either enable just that grouping or you can grant everyone execution permissions.

```
$ chmod o+x foo    # -rwxrw-r-x #  just other users
$ chmod g+x foo    # -rwxrwxr-- #  allows users in group groupX
$ chmod +x foo     # -rwxrwxr-x #  allows everyone
```

Notice in the above we're turning on the `x` bit for the different groups of bits (user, group, other).

#### What about ./bar?

This file doesn't exist, and so trying to run something that doesn't exist will give you the message you saw.

```
$ sudo ./bar
sudo: ./bar: command not found
```

Or just a regular user:

```
$ ./bar
-bash: ./bar: No such file or directory
```